# Android Room необходима помощь с сохранением

Tags: android, kotlin, room

Необходимо сохранить data class в Room

```
@Entity(tableName = "dot")
data class DotNew(
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: String,
    @SerializedName("address")
    val address: String,
    @SerializedName("apartment")
    val apartment: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("coordinates")
    @Embedded(prefix = "coord_")
    val coordinates: Coordinates,
    @SerializedName("date")
    val date: String,
    @SerializedName("distance_from_metro")
    val distanceFromMetro: Double,
    @SerializedName("items")
    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "dotsId", entity = ItemX::class)
    val items: List<ItemX>,
    @SerializedName("kkm_cheque_created")
    val kkmChequeCreated: Int,
    @SerializedName("metro")
    @Embedded(prefix = "metro_")
    val metro: Metro,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("phone")
    val phone: String,
    @SerializedName("target")
    val target: String,
    @SerializedName("time")
    val time: String,
    @SerializedName("inputs")
    var inputs: List<String>? = null,
    @SerializedName("available_statuses")
    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "dotsId", entity = DotStatus::class)
    var availableStatuses: List<DotStatus>,
    @SerializedName("dot_type")
    val type: Int,
    @SerializedName("status")
    val status: Int,
    @SerializedName("status_str")
    val statusStr: String,
    @SerializedName("revenue")
    val revenue: Int
)
```

У нас имеются связанные Data - классы:
Metro, Coordinates, ItemX, DotStatus.

Разделим на 2 группы:

1. Один к одному: Coordinates и Metro
2. Один ко многим: List< ItemX > и List< DotStatus >

**1 Один к одному**

В главном классе пометил эти поля аннотацией, например @Embedded(prefix = "coord_") (Только prefix разный)

```
@Entity(tableName = "coordinate",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
            entity = DotNew::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("dotsId"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
data class Coordinates(
    val dotsId: String = "",
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("lat")
    val lat: Double,
    @SerializedName("lng")
    val lng: Double
)
```

и

```
@Entity(tableName = "metro",
        foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
                entity = DotNew::class,
                parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
                childColumns = arrayOf("dotsId"),
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )]
)
data class Metro(
    val dotsId: String = "",
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
    @SerializedName("color")
    val color: String,
    @SerializedName("short_name")
    val shortName: String
)
```

В каждом указал связь

Так как в самих пришедших данных нету id родителя, то я создал поле, и  сам при вставке буду добавлять в конструктор Id родителя

Для выборки использую такой метод, обернув в Transaction, пока оставил Просто сущность (так как пока не знаю, нужно ли для внутренних классов LiveData указывать или нет)

```
interface MetroDao{
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM metro WHERE dotsId = :id")
    fun getById(id: String): Metro
}

interface CoordinateDao{
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM coordinate WHERE dotsId = :id")
    fun getById(id: String): Coordinates
}
```

**2 Один ко Многим**

Для этого способа я использую Relation, например

```
@Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "dotsId", entity = ItemX::class)

@Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "dotsId", entity = DotStatus::class)
```

Это вы можете увидеть в самом главном классе DotsNew.

В самих классах кроме entity ничего не добавлял, например

```
    @Entity(tableName = "item")
    
    data class ItemX(
        val dotsId : String = "",
        @PrimaryKey
        @SerializedName("id")
        val id: Int,
        @SerializedName("name")
        val name: String,
        @SerializedName("price")
        val price: Int,
        @SerializedName("quant")
        val quant: Int,
        @SerializedName("return_quant")
        var returnQuant: Int = 0
    )

@Entity(tableName = "dot_status")

class DotStatus (
    val dotsId: String = "",
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)
```

Их Dao выглядит так:

```
interface ItemDao{
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE dotsId = :id")
    fun getById(id: String) : List<ItemX>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM item")
    fun getItem() : List<ItemX>


}

interface DotsStatusDao{
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM dot_status WHERE dotsId = :id")
    fun getById(id: String): List<DotStatus>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM dot_status")
    fun getDotsStatus(): List<DotStatus>


}
Предполагается, что будет использован именно второй метод
```

Но при компиляции проекта, выдает ошибку

```
ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1D:\Project\Peshkariki-Old\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\app\peshkariki\newPesh\main\myOrdersOurCourierShuttle\DotNew.java:7: error: Entities cannot have relations.
public final class DotNew {
             ^D:\Project\Peshkariki-Old\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\app\peshkariki\newPesh\main\myOrdersOurCourierShuttle\DotNew.java:21: warning: Primary key constraint on id is ignored when being merged into com.app.peshkariki.newPesh.main.myOrdersOurCourierShuttle.DotNew
    private final com.app.peshkariki.Model.Coordinates coordinates = null;
                                                       ^D:\Project\Peshkariki-Old\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\app\peshkariki\newPesh\main\myOrdersOurCourierShuttle\DotNew.java:36: warning: Primary key constraint on id is ignored when being merged into com.app.peshkariki.newPesh.main.myOrdersOurCourierShuttle.DotNew
    private final com.app.peshkariki.Model.Metro metro = null;
                                                 ^D:\Project\Peshkariki-Old\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\app\peshkariki\Model\Metro.java:7: warning: dotsId column references a foreign key but it is not part of an index. This may trigger full table scans whenever parent table is modified so you are highly advised to create an index that covers this column.
public final class Metro {
             ^D:\Project\Peshkariki-Old\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\app\peshkariki\Model\Coordinates.java:7: warning: dotsId column references a foreign key but it is not part of an index. This may trigger full table scans whenever parent table is modified so you are highly advised to create an index that covers this column.
public final class Coordinates {
             ^
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

Пишет что сущность не должна имееть связей. WTF.

```
Entities cannot have relations.
```

Может кто подсказать, в чем проблему у меня?

И будет ли обновляться главная таблица, если изменился список сущностей - потомков в LiveData?

P.S Insert напишу позднее, как только разберусь с компиляцией проекта

**Update**
Нашел такой комментарий в документации

```
Обратите внимание, что @Relationаннотация может использоваться только в классах Pojo, Entityкласс не может иметь отношений. Это дизайнерское решение, позволяющее избежать распространенных ошибок при Entity настройке. Подробнее об этом вы можете прочитать в основной документации по комнате. При загрузке данных вы можете просто обойти это ограничение, создав классы Pojo, которые расширяют Entity.
```

Получается, мне нужно создать просто class (Например All), в котором мы уже будет ссылаться с помощью Relation и Embedded на связанные table.

Но ведь этот класс кроме связей имеет еще и свои поля, как мне их то добавить?
Получается у меня этот класс All должен кроме связей на подчиненные table иметь еще и связь на класс, который описывает оставшиеся поля, например,

```
data class All(
    @Embedded
    val dot: DotNew,

    @Embedded
    val metro: Metro,

    @Embedded
    val coordinates: Coordinates,

    @Relation(...)
    val items : List< ItemX >,

    @Relation(...)
    val statuses : List< DotsStatuses >
)
```

Верно?

Comment: Именно. Класс на описание полей и класс, объединяющий первый класс и кучу связанных с ним relation-ов

Answer (score 1):

Тут очень много кода, но он весь не имеет смысла, т.к.проблема проста и описана в ошибке - `Entities cannot have relations`. Это все что вам требуется знать =)

На самом деле согласен, что это не совсем очевидно. Но так устроен Room. Суть такая: то, что имеет аннотацию Entity, преобразуется в таблицу. И вот есть у вас класс DotNew, где куча полей, каждое из которых станет столбцом в таблице, если не помечено @Ignore. Теперь вопрос. Если одно из полей - это список других Entity сущностей, то есть целая таблица, то как уместить ее в одну клетку? Ответ - никак. Именно потому такой вариант невозможен.

Есть небольшое "исключение" для ситуации один ко многим, когда в поле может быть не список из сущностей, а один экземпляр. Тогда можно пометить это поле аннотацией Embedded и его поля будут продублированы в этот Entity. То есть если есть класс `Address(id, company_id, street, number)` и `Company(id, name, address)`, то таблица под Company будут содержать все поля `(id, name, Address.id, company_id, street, number)`. Может вам хватит такого подхода

Если все таки вам нужен список одних сущностей как поле в другой сущности, то придется создать класс-оболочку. Например, пусть у организации может быть куча адресов. Тогда делаем так:

```
class CompanyExt(val id: Int){
    @Embedded
    public Company company;
    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "company_id")
    public List<Address> addresses;
}
```

В Dao можно спокойно теперь запрашивать запросы из таблицы Company с типом возвращаемого значения CompanyExt, адреса добавятся. В ваших классах я не очень понял взаимосвязей между ними и не могу сказать как именно организовать их, но думаю с этим инструментарием вы вполне себе справитесь. Если что - больше вопросов богу вопросов =)

Comment: прочитайте, пожалуйста мое последнее обновление